# Fill array via preprocessor?

Tags: c, preprocessor

Hi and sorry if this has been asked somewhere else already.

I got a global array and my code is modular. Each module should be able to add some handler to the global array.

Basically it looks like this:

```
    #define ITEMS

    typedef struct {
      uint8_t item0;
      uint8_t item1;
    } Item_t;

    Item_t Items[]={ITEMS};
```

So I searched and tried to implement something like:

```
    ADD_ITEM(0,0);
```

The idea is, that the macro ADD_ITEM should simply expand to {0,0} and this should be added the the object-like macro ITEMS.

Any ideas or hints?

Comment: If the idea is that you put `ADD_ITEM` in each module - then it is hardly possible.

Comment: @EugeneSh. how?

Comment: How what? "Hardly" = no or not.

Comment: Ditch the global array and use setter/getter functions?

Comment: do you mean something rather than : `#define ADD_ITEM(x,y) {.item0=(x),.item1=(y)}` ? You can use it like `Item_t Items[]={ADD_ITEM(0,0),ADD_ITEM(1,0)};`

Comment: It's quite hard to guess what you are trying to do, but my guts tell me you are actually looking for a linked list, which other modules can add data to in run-time.

Comment: You can use one .h file in which you collect all your items and use this file to initialize the array.

Comment: You cannot have multiple modules adding different elements to an array at compile time.   Among other things, that would often mean the array is defined multiple times, which gives undefined behaviour.    At run time, it is possible to set something up so some code in each module calls a function which appends elements to (for example) a linked list.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Well, that's also my guess atm :-(

Comment: @Afshin Sorry, that's not what I want. The modules (different c files) don't know about each other.

Comment: @Peter I thought it might be possible to somehow extend a macro object, like connecting strings together.

Comment: @erazor - there's not such thing as a "macro object" in C, let alone an ability to "extend" one.   The C preprocessor does text substitution on source code.

Comment: @peter I know it's just some text copy&paste what the preprocessor does. I tried to stick to the correct naming. The gcc manual mentions "3.1 Object-like Macros" sorry if my naming was a bit confusing.

Comment: Yeah, okay.  The gcc docs are using the term "object-like macros" to mean a macro that will be replaced with a code fragment.  In rough terms (there are a couple of specialised exceptions) that means:  if you can't achieve what you want in normal code (without a macro), you won't be able to achieve it using a macro either.  I doubt there is a way though, for reasons given in my first comment

Answer (score 0):

IMO it is very difficult (if possible) and error prone.

IMO every module should add to your own init memory section its own init handler. That is correct and debugable way. Then on the startup you may init all the modules the way you want.

You can also create the table this way.

Answer (score 0):

> I got a global array and my code is modular.

Although not entirely inconsistent, these two claims do not rest well together.  Avoid global data.

> Each module should be able to add some handler to the global array.

Your modules could do this at run time, via some kind of initialization function, but they need help if they are to do it at compile time via the array's initializer.  The array definition will be compiled once only, and the translation unit in which it appears needs to know the array size and all its initial values.  Different translation units are compiled independently.

> So I searched and tried to implement something like:
>
> ```
> ADD_ITEM(0,0);
> ```
>
> The idea is, that the macro ADD_ITEM should simply expand to {0,0} and
>   this should be added the the object-like macro ITEMS.

There are all sorts of fun games you can play with the preprocessor, but this is not one of them.  Aside from the independent compilation thing, expansion of a macro cannot change the definition of another macro.  One macro can *use* another, but that's a different thing.

If you insist on using a global array for your data then its size and initial contents are determined at compile time.  If you want to configure those based on which modules are included then you need some kind of code generation to take care of that, or at least to bootstrap it.

Comment: To explain things a bit better. I'm writing some firmware for AVR microcontroller. In this case program size counts a lot and I'd like to avoid useless calls as much as possible. Plus I'd like to have static object sizes at runtime. I was thinking about adding/using some kind of pre-pre processor. Some kinde of code generation to work around this issue.

Comment: @erazor, you seem to be trying to change the question.  I indeed did and do recommend code generation as a viable alternative to using the preprocessor alone, but if you're hoping for specifics then that would be an entirely different question -- and one that would take some work to narrow to a suitable breadth and scope.

Comment: Currently it seems that the easy way of extending my array via macros simply does not work or is not possible. The code size is important so I somehow need to build the array before compiling. I'll keep this question open for about a day and see if someone has a nice solution. Otherwise, not connected to this question, I'll use/program a custom preprocessor, which not only creates my array but also takes out redundancy in my module files.